# Expand displaylist

Tags: opengl

I am using displaylists in OpenGL, shame on me but it works easily. However I do not know how to expand a displaylist, in other words add to it.

I tried glCallList after glNewlist, but apparently it doesn't work that way.

Is there any way to expand a displaylist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any way to expand a displaylist?

Nope.  Generate a new one containing the old and new data.